# Spring Boot sockjs + stomp, cannot get a connection

Tags: spring-boot, stomp, sockjs

I'm trying to get a sockjs + stomp connection to my spring boot websockets. This is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    private final String MESSAGE_BROKER_PREFIX = "/topic";
    private final String WEBSOCKET_PREFIX = "/sockjs-node";
    private final String REQUEST_PREFIX = "/";

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint(WEBSOCKET_PREFIX)
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker(MESSAGE_BROKER_PREFIX);
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes(REQUEST_PREFIX);
    }

}
```

And and my endpoint definition:

```
@Controller
public class Foo {

    @SubscribeMapping("/{pipelineId}/{topic}")
    private void subscribe(
            HttpSession session,
            @PathVariable String pipelineId,
            @PathVariable String topic
    ) {
        System.out.println(session.getId());
    }


    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionConnectEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getSource());
    }


    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getSessionId());
    }

}
```

And from the javascript side:

```
var ws = new SockJS('/sockjs-node');
var client = Stomp.over(ws);
var subscription = client.subscribe("/topic/foo/bar", () => {
  console.log("asdas");
});
```

but the connection does not happen and none of the methods get invoked. In the javascript console I can see:

```
>>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:/topic/lala

stomp.js:199 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Client._transmit (webpack:///./node_modules/@stomp/stompjs/lib/stomp.js?:199:26)
    at Client.subscribe (webpack:///./node_modules/@stomp/stompjs/lib/stomp.js?:468:12)
    at Object.eval (webpack:///./src/index.js?:128:27)
```

I am able to connect using `wscat --connect ws://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/902/phebsu4o/websocket`, but interestingly enough only the disconnect handler gets invoked and the connect handler doesn't. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a js client which actually works on [github](https://github.com/lahsivjar/react-stomp/blob/master/src/client.jsx).

```
import React from "react";
import SockJS from "sockjs-client";
import Stomp from "stompjs";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class SockJsClient extends React.Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    onConnect: () => {},
    onDisconnect: () => {},
    getRetryInterval: (count) => {return 1000 * count;},
    headers: {},
    autoReconnect: true,
    debug: false
  }

  static propTypes = {
    url: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    topics: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    onConnect: PropTypes.func,
    onDisconnect: PropTypes.func,
    getRetryInterval: PropTypes.func,
    onMessage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    headers: PropTypes.object,
    autoReconnect: PropTypes.bool,
    debug: PropTypes.bool
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      connected: false
    };

    this.subscriptions = new Map();
    this.retryCount = 0;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.connect();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.disconnect();
  }

  render() {
    return (<div></div>);
  }

  _initStompClient = () => {
    // Websocket held by stompjs can be opened only once
    this.client = Stomp.over(new SockJS(this.props.url));
    if (!this.props.debug) {
      this.client.debug = () => {};
    }
  }

  _cleanUp = () => {
    this.setState({ connected: false });
    this.retryCount = 0;
    this.subscriptions.clear();
  }

  _log = (msg) => {
    if (this.props.debug) {
      console.log(msg);
    }
  }

  connect = () => {
    this._initStompClient();
    this.client.connect(this.props.headers, () => {
      this.setState({ connected: true });
      this.props.topics.forEach((topic) => {
        this.subscribe(topic);
      });
      this.props.onConnect();
    }, (error) => {
      if (this.state.connected) {
        this._cleanUp();
        // onDisconnect should be called only once per connect
        this.props.onDisconnect();
      }
      if (this.props.autoReconnect) {
        this._timeoutId = setTimeout(this.connect, this.props.getRetryInterval(this.retryCount++));
      }
    });
  }

  disconnect = () => {
    // On calling disconnect explicitly no effort will be made to reconnect
    // Clear timeoutId in case the component is trying to reconnect
    if (this._timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(this._timeoutId);
    }
    if (this.state.connected) {
      this.subscriptions.forEach((subid, topic) => {
        this.unsubscribe(topic);
      });
      this.client.disconnect(() => {
        this._cleanUp();
        this.props.onDisconnect();
        this._log("Stomp client is successfully disconnected!");
      });
    }
  }

  subscribe = (topic) => {
    let sub = this.client.subscribe(topic, (msg) => {
      this.props.onMessage(JSON.parse(msg.body));
    });
    this.subscriptions.set(topic, sub);
  }

  unsubscribe = (topic) => {
    let sub = this.subscriptions.get(topic);
    sub.unsubscribe();
    this.subscriptions.delete(topic);
  }

  // Below methods can be accessed by ref attribute from the parent component
  sendMessage = (topic, msg, opt_headers = {}) => {
    if (this.state.connected) {
      this.client.send(topic, opt_headers, msg);
    } else {
      console.error("Send error: SockJsClient is disconnected");
    }
  }
}

export default SockJsClient;
```